# Twilio Rest API Helper Library, v 5.0.1, C# - MessageResource.Create function call not returning properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, twilio

I am using the Twilio REST API helper library, v 5.0.1 in my C# ASP.NET MVC Web Application.  I created the following helper class and function to send out text messages:

```
    using MyApplication.Web.Helpers;
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using Twilio;
    using Twilio.Exceptions;
    using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
    using Twilio.Types;

    namespace MyApplication.Web.Services
    {
        public class TwilioSmsSender : ISmsSender
        {
            public string AccountSid { get; set; }
            public string AuthToken { get; set; }
            public string FromPhoneNumber { get; set; }
            private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            public string SmsPrefix { get; set; }
            public string SmsSuffix { get; set; }

            public TwilioSmsSender()
            {
                //get our Twilio account info from the config file
                AccountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSid"];
                AuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];
                FromPhoneNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsService.FromPhoneNumber"];
                SmsPrefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsPrefix"];
                SmsSuffix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsSuffix"];

                if (FromPhoneNumber.Length == 10)
                {
                    FromPhoneNumber = $"+1{FromPhoneNumber}";
                }

                TwilioClient.Init(AccountSid, AuthToken);
            }

            public INotificationResponse SendTextMessage(string phoneNumber, string message, bool useFormatting = true)
            {
                var resp = new TwilioSmsSenderResponse();
                resp.Succeeded = false;
                resp.AttemptDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

                if (useFormatting)
                {
                    message = $"{SmsPrefix}{message}{SmsSuffix}";
                }

                try
                {
                    var msgResponse = MessageResource.Create(
                        to: new PhoneNumber($"+1{phoneNumber}"),
                        from: new PhoneNumber($"{FromPhoneNumber}"),
                        body: message);

                    //Previous line works (i.e, I get the text message that I'm sending out successfully).
                    //However, none of the following lines are running...
                    //As you see, this is in a try/catch block... and it doesn't go to the catch block either!

                    if (msgResponse.ErrorCode == null)
                    {
                        //successfully queued
                        resp.Succeeded = true;
                        resp.ReferenceId = msgResponse.Sid;
                        resp.AttemptDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Twilio sent an error back
                        log.Info($"Twilio sent an error back: {msgResponse}");
                        resp.Succeeded = false;
                        resp.Notes = $"ErrorCode: {msgResponse.ErrorCode}, ErrorMessage: {msgResponse.ErrorMessage}";
                        resp.AttemptDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    resp.Succeeded = false;
                    resp.Notes = ExceptionsHelper.GetExceptionDetailsAsString(e);
                    resp.AttemptDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

                    log.Error($"Twilio Error: {resp.Notes}, to: {phoneNumber}, message: {message}");
                }

                return resp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, my code is not behaving as I expected it would after the MessageResource.Create() call.  That is, the text-message is sent out correctly and I receive the SMS on my phone.  However, I expect the call to return control to my msgResponse variable and I expect the

```
if (msgResponse.ErrorCode == null) ...
```

line and subsequent lines to run but that is not happening.  I can put a breakpoint on the var msgResponse line and it will run that just fine but it does not run any code lines after that.  You’ll see that I have the call in a try/catch.  I suspected there was an exception that was occurring but it doesn’t seem so because it doesn’t go to my catch block either!  The text message is being sent successfully!  All I want to do is to get an acknowledgement back so that I can properly log it and send that information back to the routines that are calling this function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you remove the try/catch?  I took your basic code setup and tried to replicate but was unable to.  Anything going into the debugger output in VS?

Comment: ok..nm.  Think I was able to replicate it

Comment: You did find a bug in the library, I submitted a PR for it: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/pull/333 -- We'll let you know when a new version is published. In the mean time, you could look at using the CreateAsync method and making your controller action async as well. That way you're not blocking the primary thread when making requests.

Comment: @tom-vaidyan version 5.0.2 contains a fix for this and is now up in Nuget.  Thanks for the help finding the issue.  Can we send you a Twilio t-shirt as a thank you?  Drop an email to devin at twilio dot com and get one headed your way.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to bring this to light!  I'll check out the new version and report back, if I come across any issues!

Comment: FYI, I tried version 5.0.2 and can confirm that this bug has been resolved.  Thanks to Twilio for their prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

version 5.0.2 fixed this for me just update twilio to 5.0.2. they just added  .ConfigureAwait(false); with CreateAsync